# Visualize Kafka Logs in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kibana

I am trying to visualise Kafka logs through ELK stack. I particularly need to see number of messages unread by consumers in real-time. I have seen the log folder in Kafka but wasn't able to understand.

1. Where would I find information related to offsets to consumers and how do i upload it in elasticsearch ?
2. Is there a documentation about logs in kafka (e.g server.log, controller.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log folder of Kafka doesn't hold consumer lag.

You'll want to export this data from consumer applications themselves or install external monitoring like Prometheus, Burrow, or Remora, then scrape and index into Elasticsearch

Comment: We don't have consumer we are using streaming. Is consumer lag available in __consumer_offsets topic in kafka?

Comment: No. Lag is a calculated value. Kafka Streams is a high level API over top of consumer and producer. Yes, you have consumers and thus consumer groups. You can use `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI to inspect your group lag

Comment: Can you please give me linux command to get consumer lag to all topics and partitions

Comment: I trust you're able to search for that elsewhere. It's not a "Linux command". And like I've said, you can get the same if you research the above mentioned tools